# d3 node- tooltip update on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";  })
    .on("click", click)
    .on("mouseover",function (d){       
        if(d.name=="Purchased"){                  
            jQuery.getJSON("RequestHandler?usercommand=jsoncompany&subcommand=propCount&useraction=d3Tree_frm&mgmtId="+d.id+"&type="+d.name, function(json){
                var count=JSON.stringify(json.prop_purchased_count);                      
                result="Purchased Property :"+count;                                
            });
        }   
        var g = d3.select(this);              
        var info = g.append("text")
            .classed('info', true)
            .attr('x', 30)
            .attr('y', 30)         
            .text(result);      
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {      
        d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove();
    });
```

i am using above code to display basic tooltip on mouse over of a node. The problem is that when i move from one node to another tooltip value is not updated quickely it show me previous value .if i move my cursor little bit and move again to that node then only it shows me correct value of that node.
How to resolve that issue?

Comment: This is because you're sending a network request to get the content, which will take a bit. Could you get all possible tooltips and cache them?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff but i dont want to show previous node value

Comment: @LarsKotthoff how to clear previous tooltip value?

Comment: You cannot fool the network. Preload the data to be able to display it quickly.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff when i set result= "" on mousesout it does not show me tooltip on mouseover

Comment: That's because of your network query.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i think my query is working properly because when i remove result="" it shows me value

Comment: Well yes, the issue is the timing as I've said before. You're setting the text before the network query returns.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff now my result="Amount":100\n"Amount":200\n i want to show result such that after \n it appears in next line within that tooltip

Comment: See http://www.itk.ilstu.edu/faculty/javila/SVG/SVG_drawing1/word_wrap.htm

Comment: @LarsKotthoff how to apply it to result variable in my code

Comment: You should be able to find plenty of examples for that, e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321